# How to have a Mapbox callout marker shown by default and never dismissed?

Tags: ios, swift, mapbox, marker

I would like the annotation title of a `Mapbox` marker callout **shown by default** and not **tappable**. Does the API provide such possibilities?

**EDIT**:

Actually what i really need here is: how to show a **callout marker to be displayed by default and never dismissed**.

Answer (score 3):

To select an annotation and show it´s title without tapping it, this should be enough:

```
mapView.selectAnnotation(annotation, animated: true)
```

If you want to show all titles that´s not possible to do, only one is possible.

**From your comment, see below update:**
Inherit from `MKMapViewDelegate` and set `map.delegate = self` in your `viewDidLoad`.

Add a tap gesture to your map to detect taps outside `annotations`.

```
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tappedOnMap))
map.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
```

Now we have two functions to work with:

```
func tappedOnMap(_ gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer){
    mapTapped = true
}

func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didDeselect view: MKAnnotationView) {
    if mapTapped {
        map.selectAnnotation(map.annotations[1], animated: true)
    }
}
```

When you tap on your map the`tappedOnMap` function will be called. When you tap outside of an annotation the system will automatically call `didDeselect` that´s why I have declared a `mapTapped Bool` variable to keep track if the user has tapped on the map or on an annotation. In the `didDeselect` you can set which default title should be shown in the if-statement.

So basically, you detect taps outside an annotation and in the `didDeselect` function you check if it´s a tap on an annotation or on the map. If it´s on the map then you show a default or whatever you like annotation title otherwise the annotation the user has clicked on. You can also always return a default annotation, to do so remove the if-statement in the `didDeselect` function and just set `map.selectAnnotation...`

[Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hffokngj3a53s82/MapView.zip?dl=0) is  a sample project that I created for you to try with.

Comment: If you wanted to do all of the annotations, can you loop through `mapView.annotations`?

Comment: @MacStation, that will not work either. Apple has blocked so that only one annotation can be active at a time.

Comment: +1 good point. I also find out this method in the meantime but I can still select / deselect the annotation. I want to ensure the title is always visible regardless of the user's interaction with the map. I still didn't find a solution for that last part.

Comment: @tiguero, after some tweaking I managed to get it work so that you always can show the title regardless of the user's interaction with the map. See the update in my post.

Comment: I see your point but i am confused you are using MapKit API in your answer

Comment: @tiguero, it´s the same checkout their reference site [here](https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/examples/runtime-multiple-annotations/).

Comment: Sorry for the late reply but please have a look to my answer; i really expect here a solution tailored to my sdk Mapbox; also while your solution can be tried out on Mapbox it was not working properly and some glitch appear (title behind dismiss than showing up quickly after).

Answer (score 1):

This is my `answer` to my original question:

- **show a callout by default:** on the mapView you can invoke the selection of the annotation through `mapView.selectAnnotation(annotation, animated: false)`
- **make a callout not tappable:** by creating a custom `MGLCallOutView` and `disabling` interaction on it or on its inner tappable component (by setting `userinteractionenabled` to `false`). You will pass your new instance of callout through this delegate method: `func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, calloutViewFor annotation: MGLAnnotation) -> UIView?` by conforming to `MGLMapViewDelegate`.

Actually as I mentioned in my updated question what I really wanted was to prevent the callout to be hidden whenever we interact with the map.

First; one should know that this is **not** the common behavior: by tapping outside of the callout it will be dissmiss but panning or zooming on the map will not dismiss the callout.

If you still want to have this specific behavior there are two possible ways to do so:

- **make a custom `MGLAnnotationView`** with user interaction **disabled** on it. The annotation view will handle the display of the annotation title as well but won't be tappable. Make sure in that case that you can trigger the display of the callout.
- **make a custom `MGLCallOutView`** and override the `dismissCallout` method. Within this method you can ensure you don't dismiss the view.

Here are some resources examples that help me out to find those solutions:

- Custom `Annotation View`: https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/examples/annotation-views/
- Custom `Callout View`: https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/examples/custom-callout/

Please note that the **second solution** is probably more hacky and i will encourage to go for the first solution.